# Why this .map Function Does Not Work

Tags: javascript

There is this quite simple `.map` function

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 9];
var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
```

This makes sense, I perform on `numbers` the map function and provide a function that will iterate through on each element in the array.

In this next example (all these taken from mozilla, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) , I thought to myself why would we use `Array.prototype.map.call`, maybe they are just demonstrating different ways to accomplish the same goal.

```
var str = '12345';
Array.prototype.map.call(str, function(x) {
  return x;
}).reverse().join('');
```

So I rewrote this as

```
var str = '12345';
var stringy = str.map(function(x) {
  return x;
}).reverse().join('');
```

Except I get an error "str.map is not a function(...)"
Why is this?

Comment: Should it be `str.split("").map()`? If I'm not wrong, [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is for arrays, not strings

Comment: `str` is not an array so it doesn't have a `map` method. `Array.prototype.map.call` converts the string into an array.

Comment: @LambdaNinja You should post this as an answer.

Comment: In one above snippet you know how to do `Array.prototype.map.call(str...` and not in the one that you stumble upon... This is the real question...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because `str` is a string, and strings do not have the `map()` function.

`map()` is a function of the array type.

Comment: I thought even the string type all the way up the chain had inherited from array. But this is good to know.